# リモートのデフォルトブランチを取得したい

Tags: git

ある git url (例: git@hogehoge.com:foo/bar.git) があったとき、このリモートのデフォルトブランチを取得したいです。

何も引数指定せずに clone してみたときにチェックアウトされているブランチが、デフォルトブランチであるので、原理的には取得可能ではあると思っています。かといって、わざわざ clone するのはあまりにも手間です。

### 質問:

- リモートのデフォルトブランチを取得することは可能ですか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GitHubなどではデフォルトブランチと呼称していますが、厳密には `HEAD` が指すブランチです。そして `HEAD` の正体は symref と呼ばれる、ref を参照する ref です。

#### リモートのHEADが指すブランチを文字列で取得する

リモートに存在する ref とそれに対応するコミットを一覧する `git ls-remote` というコマンドがあるのですが、`--symref` オプションを付けると参照先のref (この場合ブランチ) も表示します。

```
$ git ls-remote --symref https://github.com/ruby/ruby.git HEAD
ref: refs/heads/trunk   HEAD
532bbd4ebf7a90c101a4cb42a680bbb0e29e64d8        HEAD
```

#### 参考

- [What determines default branch after "git clone"? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18726037/2818869)
- [Get the branch name pointed at by HEAD in a remote repository without cloning the remote - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41925348/2818869)